# Word Press Admin Panel Search Results

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a Custom Post type defined in one site i am doing as follows:

```
$labels = array(
   'name' => 'Clients',
   'singular_name' => 'Client',
   'add_new' => 'Add New',
   'all_items' => 'All Items',
   'add_new_item' => 'Add New',
   'edit_item' => 'Edit Item',
   'new_item' => 'Add New',
   'view_item' => 'View Item',
   'search_item' => 'Search Item',
   'not_found' => 'Item Not Found',
   'not_found_in_trash' => 'Item Not Found',
   'parent_item_color' => 'Parent Item'
 );

 $args = array(
   'labels' => $labels,
   'public' => true,
   'show_ui' => true,
   'has_archive' => true,
   'publicly_queryable' => true,
   'query_var' => true,
   'rewrite' => true,
   'capability_type' => 'post',
   'hierarchical' => false,
   'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'revisions'),
   'taxonomies' => array('category', 'post_tag'),
   'menu_position' => 20,
   'exclude_from_search' => false,
   'menu_icon'   => 'dashicons-admin-users'
);

register_post_type('clients', $args);
```

My problem is that when I try to search my posts in the clients section in the admin panel (not a search form, but the wordpress admin panel) the results shown are from the regular posts, not the clients custom post type. Obviously I need the results for the clients. I am missing an argument here or something? Or this is something you should do with a filter? I am a bit lost here, I have to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

try adding:
`'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'your-slug-name')),`
to the `$args` array for your custom post type.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I am going to answer my own question. Actually, there was nothing wrong with my post type. The guilty guy here was a pre_get_posts that I had without !is_admin() and it was propagating the functionality to the admin panel as well. Bad time looking for it... Thanks anyway